# How to run debugging with pytest via normal launch settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I tried running this morning:

```
{
    "name": "pytest",
    "type": "python",
    "request": "launch",
    "module": "pytest",
    "justMyCode": false,
    "args": [
        "-vv",
        "${file}",
    ],
},
```

with debugging and VSCode completely ignored my breakpoints when I run it on my unit tests. It was all working last week.

Now I got this testing framework which stops at breakpoints as expected. I want the same for normal run with pytest, I ran out of ideas why would it not debug during normal module launch.

I tried reinstalling the Python extension in the VSCode and couple of different launch configurations, and nothing seems to solve the problem.

If that's no longer possible, how to set additional arguments to pytest **so that they work** (because using "python.testing.pytestArgs" in settings.json does not work) and where to put "justMyCode: false" for testing framework to recognize it since launch is no longer viable? (and launch with purpose from docs does not work as well)